# Dense subset on complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $M$ a dense subset of $X$ with the proterty that every Cauchy sequence of $M$ has a limit inside $X$. Show that $X$ is complete.

With contradiction:

Let $(x_{n})$ be a Cauchy sequence of $X$ such that it doesn't converge on $X$.

We can take a subsequence  $x_{k_{n}}\subseteq M$ and we know that $x_{k_{n}}\rightarrow x,\, x\in X$
and therefore we have that  $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ because $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy and if one subsequence converges to $x$ we know that $(x_{n})$ is also converges to $x$ and that's a contradiction.

Is my proof complete, thank you.

Comment: You have no reason to think that **any** $x_n$ is in $M$, let alone some subsequence. Show instead that there is a Cauchy sequence in $M$ that is equivalent to $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

Comment: I didn't say that every $x_{n}$ is in $M$ i said i can find a subsequence of $x_{n}$ thats in $M$, i don't understand what you mean that will show that $M$ is complete not $X$ or am i mistaken ?

Comment: You've took a sequence in X but then assumed there is a subsequence in M. How do you assume that?

Comment: @PetrosK: I know what you said. I pointed out that you cannot choose such a subsequence, because it’s quite possible that **none** of the points $x_n$ is in $M$. And no, what I suggested will not show that $M$ is complete; it’s a way to use the completeness of $M$ to show that $X$ is complete.

Comment: i assume that since $M$ is a subset of $X$ i can always find a subsequence in $M$, how can i prove it any hints?

Comment: i can simple say that since $M$ is dense in $X$ , for every $x\epsilon X \ni cauchy (y_{n}),y_{n}\rightarrow x$ and that will do it?

Comment: @PetrosK: You can’t prove it: it’s not true. And no, it is not enough to know that point of $X$ is the limit of a sequence in $M$. In my first comment I told you how to start on what you’ll have to do.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Could someone verify my  solution below thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct me if i am wrong cause i am not sure about my anwser but i couldn't come up with anything else.

Let $x_{n}\epsilon X$ and $x'_{n}\epsilon M\bigcap B(x_{n},\frac{1}{n})$

$\Rightarrow $ $d(x'_{n},x_{n})<\frac{1}{n}$ $\Rightarrow $ $d(x'_{n},x_{n})\rightarrow 0$ (1)

i take $m\geq n\geq n_{0}$ and i have $d(x'_{m},x'_{n})\leq d(x'_{m},x_{n})+d(x_{n},x'_{n})$ $\overset{(1)}{\rightarrow}0$

and that says $x'_{n}$ is Cauchy $\Rightarrow $ $x'_{n}\rightarrow x\epsilon X$

now
$d(x_{n},x)\leq d(x_{n},x'_{n})+d(x'_{n},x)\rightarrow 0$

and that proves that $X$ is complete

Comment: i corrected the previous answer i think this one its ok

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach: let $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. For each $n\geq 1$, pick $x_n'\in M\cap B(x_n, 1/n)$.

1. Show that $(x_n')_{n\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence too.

By assumption, there is $x\in X$ with $x_n'\to x$.

2. Show that $x_n \to x$ as well.

Comment: this maybe a silly question but how do i know that  $M\cap B(x_n, 1/n)\neq \varnothing $

Comment: Because $M$ is dense and $B(x_n,1/n)$ is open.